# Add generic fields to rails JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I need to render JSON response for the REST api in which I need to include additional JSON fields that are not part of the model being rendered. I did read this [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html) about ActiveModel where it suggests to use the ":methods" option to call another method where I can additional generic fields.

```
def add_fields
  { "field1" => "true" }
end

if @user.save
  render :json => @user.as_json(:only => [:username, :org], :methods => [:add_fields])
endif
```

However, when the JSON response is received only the username & org fields are returned in the JSON. The additional parameters defined in the method "add_fields" are not added. What is it that I am missing due to which additional fields are not being added to JSON response. Or is there a better way to add generic fields (not part of model) in JSON response?

Comment: Are you sure you implemented the add_fields method in User?

Comment: My fault, I had added the method in another model. Thanks for pointing it out. The issue is fixed now

Comment: Good to hear that, I posted my comment as an answer for you to be able to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you forgot to implement the `#add_fields` method in User.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on my own User model and it worked just fine.

```
2.0.0p195 :002 > user.as_json(only: [:first_name, :last_name], methods: [:full_name])
{
    "first_name" => "Cody",
     "last_name" => "Russell",
      :full_name => "Cody Russell"
}
```

Are you sure you have the method defined, and it's a public method?